# how to change the VS Code snippet path

Tags: visual-studio-code

javascript snippets are placed in a folder named appdata\roaming\code\user\ (on windows PC ). How do I change that folder?  Would like to place visual studio code snippets in a onedrive shared folder.

thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can change the snippets folder, but you could move your folder to OneDrive and then make a symlink in its place.

```
move "C:\Users\<user>\appdata\roaming\code\user\" "C:\Users\<user>\OneDrive\code\"
mklink /d "C:\Users\<user>\appdata\roaming\code\user\" "C:\Users\<user>\OneDrive\code\user\"
```